# Can I Implement google reCAPTCHA version 1.0 (old) in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

If we can implement, how to validate user response?

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=<Public Key>"></script>
<noscript>
               <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=<Public Key>" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
               <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field"></textarea>
               <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

Comment: Read "Verify User Response" portion of this blog.http://venkatbaggu.com/google-recaptcha-asp-net-mvc/ . Its for recaptcha v2.0. But the similar technique will work for recaptcha v1.0

Comment: I tried that one but it does not give any response. var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"], the above lines gives null @Abdul Rauf Mujahid

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class such as

```
public class GoogleReCaptcha
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("error-codes")]
    public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }
}
```

and a method in a service class that is called by your `controller` such as:

```
public bool ValidateReCaptcha(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Request["g-recaptcha-response"];

        var client = new WebClient();
        var reply =
            client.DownloadString(
                string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", ApplicationManager.GoogleRecaptchaSecret, response));

        var captchaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleReCaptcha>(reply);

        if (!captchaResponse.Success)
        {
            if (captchaResponse.ErrorCodes.Count <= 0)
                throw new Exception("Re-Captcha Returned False for Success Without any Error Codes");

            switch (captchaResponse.ErrorCodes[0].ToLower())
            {
                case ("missing-input-secret"):
                    throw new Exception("Re-Captcha Secret Parameter is Missing");

                case ("invalid-input-secret"):
                    throw new Exception("Re-Captcha Secret Parameter is Invalid or Malformed");

                case ("missing-input-response"):
                    modelState.AddModelError("", "Capthca error, retry!.");
                    break;

                case ("invalid-input-response"):
                    modelState.AddModelError("", "Captcha error, retry!");
                    break;

                default:
                    modelState.AddModelError("", "Captcha error, retry!");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And you can call your method in a `POST` controller action like:

```
if (!SomeService.ValidateReCaptcha(ModelState))
    return View(model);
```

Comment: Here I am not getting any response am I doing any mistake

Comment: You need to show me your code before I can answer that.